# Need assistance with redirecting page after successful login

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my login, just type in any random email and password. It's not supposed to let you login.

Okay so after a user successfully logs in, it has to redirect to a new page. So when I change "header: Connect Kitty.html" it works but when I type in an email that doesn't exist, and a password, then it still leads me to the page which it shouldn't. Any help I can get, thank you.

I've tried changing "header: index.php" to "header: Connect Kitty.html" and it works when I type in an email and password, but when I type an email and a password that doesn't exist, it still redirects me to the page which it shouldn't.

```
     if($userData){
        $sessData['userLoggedIn'] = TRUE;
        $sessData['userID'] = $userData['id'];
        $sessData['status']['type'] = 'success';
        $sessData['status']['msg'] = 'Welcome '.$userData['first_name'].'!';
    }else{
        $sessData['status']['type'] = 'error';
        $sessData['status']['msg'] = 'Wrong email or password, please try again.'; 
    }
}else{
    $sessData['status']['type'] = 'error';
    $sessData['status']['msg'] = 'Enter email and password.'; 
}
//store login status into the session
$_SESSION['sessData'] = $sessData;
//redirect to the home page
header("Location: Connect Kitty.html");
```

When the location is index.php, it works and it doesn't let me go in the page with a false email or password. But when I change it to Connect Kitty.html or any other file name, it lets me go in the new page with a false email and password. It says "Wrong email or password." When I go back, but it still lets me go on the page.

Comment: You haven't included any code pertaining to either usernames or passwords in your question.

Comment: Update your question with the code

Comment: Always stop code execution after your header redirect. `header("Location: ********.php"); exit;`

Comment: Thank you, my login form still directs me to the home page when I type in a false email or password though. Do you have any suggestions on what I should try?

Comment: What's going to stop someone from just visiting Connect Kitty.html? If you want a secure page that requires login, then that page would need to check the session for a valid user and bounce anyone out who was not a valid user.

Comment: Thank you for that, I'm just trying to work on one problem first, I have that covered.